# Grouping a IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I have an object diceRolls that is a IEnumerable>.  A data set looks like
{{ 1 , 1 },
{ 1 , 2 },
{ 1 , 3 },
{ 1 , 4 },
{ 1 , 2}}

I need to get a result set that groups the common sets and sums up the total number of rows of that set.

I tried the GroupBy method like this:

```
var aggregate = sorted.GroupBy(rolls => rolls, rolls => rolls);
```

But it did not group anything and I could find no fields inside of the rolls object to group by so my only choice was the whole object itself.  How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by common set- the same totals 2-4 and 3-3, or 2-4, 4-2 would be a group?

Comment: The same numbers, so {1 , 2} and {1, 2,} would be groups but not {2, 4} and {3, 3}.  I have already sorted the results so I will never have {2, 1}, I will always have {1, 2}.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to `GroupBy` custom `IEqualityComparer` which implements sequence equals so group by will threat {1, 2} and {1, 2} as the same. But if you know, that your rolls has only 2 elements when you can use anonymous type and its equals implementation:

```
var sorted = new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 3 }, new[] { 2, 2 } };
var grouped = sorted.GroupBy(roll => new { r0 = roll[0], r1 = roll[1] });
var backToArrays = grouped.Select(g => new[] { g.Key.r0, g.Key.r1 });
```

This code will produce {{ 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 2, 2 }}. Is it that you need?

Comment: Yes, except I would have any number of elements from 2 to 20.